# IMO Combinatorics C2 proof check

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, combinatorial-proofs

We have $2^m$ sheets of paper, with the number $1$ written on each of them. We perform the following operation. In every step we choose two distinct sheets; if the numbers on the two sheets are a and b, then we erase these numbers and write the number $a + b$ on both sheets. Prove that after $m2^{m-1}$ steps, the sum of the numbers on all the sheets is at least $4^m$.

The problem is C2 from this shortlist:

https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2014SL.pdf

It's a nice one to struggle with because the statement quickly appears to be obviously true (after a bit of counting and experimenting), but it's hard to prove.

My solution:

First note that pairing two sheets with the same number at each step until each sheet reads $2^m$ yields a sum of $4^m$ in exactly $m2^{m-1}$ steps.

We prove that this construction yields the minimal sum over all possible sums that can be constructed in $m2^{m-1}$ steps.

Note that this construction is minimal over all constructions in which sheets are paired only with other sheets containing the same number as themselves (since it increases the number on a given sheet from $1$ to $2^m$ in exactly $m$ steps, and an $m+1$th step for a given pair of sheets would clearly cause a greater addition to the final sum than any of the steps here).

Suppose it were possible to construct a smaller sum in the same number of steps. Then there must be some sheet $A$ which is at some step paired with a sheet $B$ containing a number smaller than its own.

Suppose $A$ is initially paired with a sheet containing the same number as itself (thus doubling its total) $s$ times, and $B$ paired with such a sheet $t$ times where $s>t$, and then in what will be the $s+1$'th step involving $A$ and the $t+1$'th step  involving $B$, $A$ and $B$ are paired giving each the same total, namely $2^s+2^t$.

Consider now the case where for their respective remainders of $m$ steps, both $A$ and $B$ are paired with sheets containing the same number as themselves and hence having their totals doubled at each step.

Then the numbers on $A$ and $B$ after each has performed its $m$ steps will be

$(2^s+2^t)2^{m-(s+1)}$ and $(2^s+2^t)2^{m-(t+1)}$ respectively.

Since the sum of these two numbers is > $2\times2^m$, we see that pairing $A$ with a number smaller than itself at a single step and $B$ with a number larger than itself a single step does not lead to a smaller final sum.

So if it is possible to reduce the final sum after the step at which $A$ and $B$ are paired, it must be by subsequently either pairing $A$ with at least one further sheet containing a smaller number, or by pairing $B$ with at least one sheet containing a smaller number. But each time $A$ or $B$ is paired with a sheet $C$ containing a smaller number, $C$ is being paired with a sheet containing a larger number. [incomplete]

Hence the sum constructed initially is minimal.

Edited in response to comments, rethinking conclusion, suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Write the question itself in your post rather than making us have to scroll through several pages to find it in your link.

Comment: Did you read their solution, in particular Comment 3 that says "An intuitive strategy to minimise the sum of numbers is that in every step we choose the two smallest numbers. We may call this the greedy strategy. In the following paragraphs we prove that the greedy strategy indeed provides the least possible sum of numbers."? How does your solution compare to theirs?

Comment: As a quick read, I see the following issues (but maybe you patched them up?) 1/ Because of the term "or would reach" when you are defining $A$ as "there must be some sheet $A$ whose number reaches (or would reach) $2^m$ in more than $m$ steps",, does not imply that you "fill in the remaining steps if it is not reached" to conclude that $A = (2^s + 2^t) 2^{m - (s+1) }$.  $\quad$ 2/ Furthermore, you didn't consider the case where they are not subsequently paired with their respective values for the remainders of m (or however many they actually had) steps.

Comment: Thanks Calvin. I read comment 3 and it's closer but still a bit different to what I was trying to do - they've gone to much greater lengths to make it rigorous. I've tidied it up a bit but I'm not sure if it's possible to rescue this attempt from here? The casework seems too slippery.

Comment: I did a reread, and have the following concerns 1/ You many not assume that each piece is used exactly $m$ times. If that is an assumption you're making, be explicit with it. $\quad$ 2/ You many only assume that A and B are paired with the same number as itself before the combination (by making them the first pair of unequal combination) or after the combination (by making them the last pair), but not always before and after. (It seems to be an assumption that you're making, esp based on how the last paragraph is written)

Comment: 3/ You haven't really proven anything so far. EG Why couldn't be have done an (A,B) then (B,C) then (C,A)? $\quad$   4/ What is the structure of the proof? What are you hoping to accomplish with these initial steps? I don't see how to go from your current assumptions, to the general case.  $\quad$ 5/ Relatedly, any solution that goes "Assumes X exactly happens" will be treated with some suspicion about dealing with the general case, unless there is also an "Assume not X exactly happens".